# Using iptables for setting an IP destination for a specific IP source

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

### Situation:

I've already created different IP aliases, (each with a different virtual Mac Address too).

```
ip link add link eth0 address 00:11:11:11:11:11 eth0.1 type macvlan

ifconfig eth0.1 172.17.1.15/21 up
```

What I want now is to set a specific destination for each IP alias.

---

### *For instance:*

*Router: 172.17.0.1/21*

*eth0> 172.17.1.14/21*

*eth0.1> 172.17.1.15/21*

*eth0.2> 172.17.1.16/21*

*I need now the eth0:1 to be the source to access: https://www.google.com.*

*And the eth0:2 the source to access: https://www.netflix.com.*

---

### What I have tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 172.17.1.15 -o eth0.1 -j SNAT --source-to 172.217.16.228
```

(172.217.16.228 = www.google.com)

I have been trying many similar commands with no success.

Comment: This looks like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please edit your question and state what your actual goal is (why do you need several IP addresses). General comments: (1) Several IP addresses for a single machine in a single subnet will nearly always cause headaches, often in ways you don't expect. (2) In many cases, using the macvlan inside a network namespace is a better option. (3) You may also want to look at *policy routing*.

Comment: (1) What I am trying to see this way is if our router's speed throttling can be bypassed in order to find a better option/solution. The VPN is not a way for bypassing because the speed throttling is set for every single IP or MacAddress. (2) I will keep using it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SNAT --to-source 172.217.16.228
```

Instead of:

```
SNAT --source-to 172.217.16.228
```

You can also try adding a rule in the INPUT / OUTPUT table instead of NAT (or use PREROUTING with DNAT).

Edit: I'm also not sure if decimals are valid for network interface aliases, try eth0:1 instead of eth0.1

Comment: The correct one is "source-to" yes, thanks, but it does not create the route correctly. Or at least, I can't see it. Could this be solved with "ip route" command?